# How to Add A Messaging Box To Your App Swift IOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

How can I add an area where users of the app can type a message and then I can save the message to a database.

1)How can I add an area where users of the app can type a message? Not a textfield, as the message may be multiple lines It should be somewhat like the image I have posted of the yik yak application. [image]

2) What service can I use to save the message? (As I am currently using parse for the rest of the applications, would that be a viable option?). I need the message to be saved, and then retrieved by other users, somewhat like the application called yik yak.

Comment: Have you already looked into UITextView?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for something that is better suited for the task. @DanielT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use UITextView instead of UITextField for the message input.

2) Use whatever works for you. You can store the data in Core Data, or in NSUserDefaults, or in a file (for that last one, `NSString writeToFile:` makes it especially easy.

Comment: How would I then get the text from it? @DanielT.

Comment: The same way you get the text from a UITextField. Check the docs for more information. If you have more questions, post some code to get help.